# How to change VisualState Setter property via code in C#?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I have the following VisualState Setter properties in my UWP app.

```
 <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
            <VisualState x:Name="Desktop">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="800" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="DesktopAds.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    <Setter Target="DesktopAds.(Grid.Row)" Value="0" />
                    <Setter Target="DesktopAds.(Grid.Column)" Value="4" />
                    <Setter Target="DesktopAds.(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Value="1" />
                    <Setter Target="MainScrollViewer.(Grid.Row)" Value="0" />
                    <Setter Target="MainScrollViewer.(Grid.Column)" Value="2" />
                    <Setter Target="MediaControl.Height" Value="600" />

                    <Setter Target="MobileAds.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    <Setter Target="MainScrollViewer.(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Value="1" />

                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Phone">
                <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                    <AdaptiveTrigger MinWindowWidth="0" />
                </VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <VisualState.Setters>
                    <Setter Target="DesktopAds.Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />

                    <Setter Target="MediaControl.Height" Value="400" />

                    <Setter Target="DesktopAds.(Grid.Row)" Value="1" />
                    <Setter Target="DesktopAds.(Grid.Column)" Value="0" />
                    <Setter Target="DesktopAds.(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Value="3" />

                    <Setter Target="MobileAds.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    <Setter Target="MainScrollViewer.(Grid.Row)" Value="0" />
                    <Setter Target="MainScrollViewer.(Grid.Column)" Value="0" />
                    <Setter Target="MainScrollViewer.(Grid.ColumnSpan)" Value="5" />
                </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

I want to have a trial and a paid version of my app with the trial version having ads and the paid version without ads. I am using LicenseInformation.IsTrial property to determine whether the app is trial or paid version and when the app is loading I am making the visibility of DesktopAds and MobileAds as collapsed. But because of the AdaptiveTriggers the DesktopAds and MobileAds visibility gets changed to visible and I still see the ads. How to make the visibility permanently collapsed in my paid version of the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you really want to do is to use Visual State Groups. Like this:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="LayoutVisualStateGroup">
        <VisualState x:Name="Desktop" />
        <VisualState x:Name="Phone" />        
    </VisualStateGroup>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="AdvertVisualStateGroup">
        <VisualState x:Name="ShowAds" />
        <VisualState x:Name="HideAds" />        
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Then, let the adaptive triggers handle layout, and let your code-behind handle hiding and showing your adverts. Because you put states into groups, they are mutually exclusive, and can be set indep. Sort of like how a button can be both `pressed` and `enabled`. They do it with groups. This is a very typical approach, by the way.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Change the visual state programatically:

```
VisualStateManager.GoToState(yourPageHere, "Phone", useTransitions: false);
```